# CCleaner equivalent?

Tags: software-recommendation

I frequently use ccleaner to (*cover my tracks*), clean up unused data stored on my computer from web traffic and hotfixes on my windows system.

I was wondering if there is a piece of software that does the same thing for ubuntu that ccleaner does for windows?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) (Available in the software center)

> BleachBit quickly frees disk space and tirelessly guards your privacy. Free cache, delete cookies, clear Internet history, shred temporary files, delete logs, and discard junk you didn't know was there. Designed for Linux and Windows systems, it wipes clean 90 applications including Firefox, Internet Explorer, Adobe Flash, Google Chrome, Opera, Safari,and more. Beyond simply deleting files, BleachBit includes advanced features such as shredding files to prevent recovery, wiping free disk space to hide traces of files deleted by other applications, and vacuuming Firefox to make it faster. Better than free, BleachBit is open source.

## [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)

> Ubuntu Tweak is an application to
> config Ubuntu easier for everyone.
>
> It provides many useful desktop and
> system options that the default
> desktop environment doesn't provide.
>
> With its help, you will enjoy with the
> experience of Ubuntu!

Comment: the link doesn't work for me

Comment: BleachBit is great, I use it regularly.
@Yannick Rochon: `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-tweak bleachbit`

Comment: In Ubuntu and Debian's repository the version of BleachBit is often ancient, so you may want to grab [fresh .deb installer files from the official BleachBit site](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the user switcher applet to open a Guest Session.

Do whatever it is you need to do and then log out.

The history is not associated with your account and in any case and is lost when the guest session ends.

Answer (score 2):

I practice various methods to auto clean my disk which I'm mentioning here. Hope this helps.

1.Use Disk Usage Analyzer by going to Applications->Accessories->Disk Usage Analyzer and click on the Scan Filesystem at the top to get it to analyze your disk usage pattern.

Now u can easily analyze which files are waste and its time to trash them.

2.Clean up your package installation using the following commands.

clearing up of the partial packages: `sudo apt-get autoclean`

clearing up of the apt-cache :`sudo apt-get clean`

cleaning up of any unused dependencies: `sudo apt-get autoremove`

A good practice to avoid any left behind is to use the autoremove command whenever you want to uninstall an application.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove application-name
```

3.Use Computer Janitor by going in Administration->Computer Janitor. It automatically scan and displays all the unused packages which can easily be deleted. But be careful it also shows the .deb packages installed manually(i.e. not using apt-get).

And I'd suggest u to check out [this](http://maketecheasier.com/8-ways-to-maintain-a-clean-lean-ubuntu-machine/2008/10/07) page for more advanced techniques..

Hope that was useful.

Comment: check this one also http://maketecheasier.com/4-more-ways-to-clean-up-your-ubuntu-machine/2010/08/06

Answer (score 1):

Computer Janitor can clean up old kernels and a bunch of other stuff.  For history/cookies/etc, I like to just set Firefox to delete all that every time I close the browser.

Comment: Beware of Computer Janitor it can screw things up....

Comment: The only "screw up" I've heard of (which, goodness, you're a bit late, hasn't it been gone for a year?) is that people would add software without repositories that maintained that software. Computer Janitor would then regard that software as unmaintained and unsupported (*because it was*) and then remove (or offer to?) it.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to support BleachBit here as it does more than things like Janitor, like tracking down .DS_Store files (I have a Mac on my LAN) and thumbs.db and other trash files.  I also like Ubuntu Tweak for easy, safe kernal cleanup.