# Does Ubuntu Automatically Perform Maintenance in the Background?

Tags: performance

I know with windows, it likes to go nuts when you're idling, and I was just wondering if there was any sort of similar maintenance tasks that I should be concerned about with Ubuntu.

I know you don't have to worry about fragmentation with Linux (due to ext2/3), and I was just wondering if there was anything other common maintenance tasks that would be pointless for Ubuntu or Linux in general.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12409/do-you-ever-have-to-do-any-regular-maintenance?rq=1 ;)

Comment: Have a look at the scripts in `/etc/cron*`. They are used to perform (pseudo-)periodical (maintenance) tasks like checking for package updates.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu, like other Linux systems, has a group of scheduled maintenance tasks that run automatically that maintain the system logs, temporary files, and other tasks. Most of these tasks are scheduled as `cron` jobs that run during anticipated period of low use (like during the overnight hours) but will also run if they have not been performed after a certain time period has elapsed.

File system checks are run on startup if a hard system shutdown was detected. From an end-user standpoint, there is little that you have to do other than performing periodic system updates that can be scheduled through Update Manager.