# How to move a starter from the Launcher to the "System Settings" window?

Tags: unity, launcher

I just installed the application [Computer Janitor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CleanupCruft).
The icon is now accessible in the Unity Launcher.

Personally I think that the Unity toolbar is great for "normal" applications, but for system applications I prefer that they are not so easily accessible and the best place is then in the "System Settings" window.

So I can remove this icon from the Unity Launcher, but how can I add it to the "System Settings" window?

[image]

Comment: Confusing: In Ubuntu Software Center I find this application as "Computer Janitor". But http://packages.ubuntu.com/computer-janitor-gtk doesn't exist - the package `computer-janitor-gtk` itself links in its description to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CleanupCruft - where this application is called `system-cleaner` - which doesn't exist in Ubuntu Software Center ...

Comment: my translation was not right, the  english name is **Computer Janitor** as you suggested - thanks for editing my question.

Comment: @Boris - I would strongly advise you **against** using computer janitor.  It breaks more things than it fixes.  If you want a *cleaner* - try bleachbit or ubuntu-tweak as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/2243/ccleaner-equivalent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Add the starter to "System Settings":**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/computer-janitor-gtk.desktop`, enter your root password when asked.

Add `X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;` to the line "Categories=System;Settings;PackageManager;GTK;".

Add the new line `X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=computer-janitor-gtk` to the end of the file, save and close.

**Remove the icon from the Launcher** via rightclick → `Remove from Launcher`.

And you get:

[image: system settings]

---

Launchers of applications are stored in ~/.local/share/applications or in /usr/share/applications/ (which to edit you have to open with `gksu nautilus` - but don't mess up your system!). Note: When an application becames updated, often the .desktop file becames updated, too (in /usr/..., not in ~/.local/...)

More info about Launchers you find [in the Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

Comment: Perfect it works. Could you give me more details so I can later do it for any other applications. So far I understood that we get a `*.desktop` file for every applications but I would never find myself to do these modifications without your advise. Is there a link describing the content of these `*.desktop` file ?

Comment: Thanks for adding the image! I updated the answer with some details.